# Twitter OAuth Request Token Failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-oauth

I am trying to integrate Twitter Sign-in with the Twitter API. When I attempt to request an OAuth Token, I receive a 400 status code (215 Twitter Code) and am dumbfounded as to why. I followed the API documentation to a T.

Here are the links to the documentation I followed:

[Implementing Sign in with Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter)

[POST oauth/request_token](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token)

[Authorizing a request](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request)

[Creating a signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html)

And here is my code:

```
const http_method = 'POST';
const base_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
const oauth_callback = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
const oauth_consumer_key = 'consumerKey';
const oauth_consumer_secret = 'consumerSecret';
const oauth_nonce = crypto
  .randomBytes(32)
  .toString('ascii')
  .replace(/\W/g, '');
const oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
const oauth_signing_key = encodeURIComponent(oauth_consumer_secret) + '&';
const oauth_timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
const oauth_version = '1.0';

// Normalized parameter string
const parameter_string =
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_callback') +
  '=' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_callback) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_consumer_key') +
  '=' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_consumer_key) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_nonce') +
  '=' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_nonce) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature_method') +
  '=' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_signature_method) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_timestamp') +
  '=' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_timestamp) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_token') +
  '=' +
  '' +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_version') +
  '=' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_version);

// Create signature string
const signature_string =
  encodeURIComponent(http_method) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent(base_url) +
  '&' +
  encodeURIComponent(parameter_string);

// Create OAuth signature
const oauth_signature = crypto
  .createHmac('sha1', oauth_signing_key)
  .update(signature_string)
  .digest('base64');

// Header parameter string
const oauth_header_string =
  'OAuth ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_callback') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_callback) +
  '"' +
  ', ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_consumer_key') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_consumer_key) +
  '"' +
  ', ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_nonce') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_nonce) +
  '"' +
  ', ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_signature) +
  '"' +
  ', ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature_method') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_signature_method) +
  '"' +
  ', ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_timestamp') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_timestamp) +
  '"' +
  ', ' +
  encodeURIComponent('oauth_version') +
  '=' +
  '"' +
  encodeURIComponent(oauth_version) +
  '"';

// Request OAuth Token
axios
  .post(base_url, {
      headers: {
          Authorization: oauth_header_string,
      },
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a library that implements OAuth 1.0a? I found an example that may provide some direction : https://webapplog.com/node-js-oauth1-0-and-oauth2-0-twitter-api-v1-1-examples/